# Where can I find pre-trained language models in English and German?

Tags: neural-networks, natural-language, language-models

Where can I find (more) pre-trained language models? I am especially interested in **neural network based** models for **English and German**.

I am aware only of [Language Model on One Billion Word Benchmark](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/lm_1b) and [TF-LM: TensorFlow-based Language Modeling Toolkit](https://github.com/lverwimp/tf-lm).

I am surprised not to find a greater wealth of models for different frameworks and languages.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what is your task but you can look to:

- SpaCy https://spacy.io/models/ - a number of 'multi-task' models, both for EN and DE
- Tensfor Flow Hub https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/modules/text - 'just' embeddings
- FastText https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/english-vectors.html - again embeddings

Comment: In addition, huggingface now hosts a large collection of models (and code to use them)